# Printing PDFs on Commercial Printer

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I recently started a project to move reports to be generated as PDFs. I generate many reports into many PDFs. At the end of the Process, I use PDFSharp to combine the results into a single PDF. This has all worked fine.

However, the Printer has 6 different trays. It pulls certain paper for different paper types (Letter, A4, ect...).

My combined PDF and single document PDFs all print on plain white paper. I need invoices to print on perforated paper sources, but I have no way to tell the printer that this paper type is different.

The printer is a KODAK NEXPRESS SX Platform.

http://graphics.kodak.com/US/en/product/printers_presses/comm_sheet/digital_color/nexpress/sx/support/drivers/default.htm

How can I make the PDF be recognized as a different Paper Type?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kodak Nexpress Printers all support the *JDF* job ticketing format.

You have to embed a valid JDF file into the PDF. The JDF will hold the job description (including which PDF page should print on which paper type).

If you don't know how to create a valid JDF for the Nexpress, ask your friendly vendor sales person for a copy of the respective documentation. It's free for an expensive printer like that....    ;)

Comment: Thanks Kurt! Thank you so much for a direction on this! I'll mark this as the answer after I contact our vendor!

Comment: Hey Kurt, I said the wrong Printer name. It is a Kodak Digimaster. We're still in the process of checking if JDF is supported. Would this printer still work with JDF you think?

Comment: @ribald: According to **[this presentation](http://www.cip4.org/document_archive/documents/2009/ws_stuttgart_2009/JDF_Symposium_2009_08_Kodak.pdf)** (page 7) given at the JDF symposium 2009 in Stuttgart, the Digimaster supports JMF and JDF. The Digimaster may need a firmware update, though (the first models came to market already more than 15 years ago, IIRC).

Comment: thanks. Turns out the JDF isn't supported with my printer though. I found documentation that tells of how to use postscript that seems promising. It seems to work, but I'm having issues with larger postscript files.

Comment: @ribald: It may also be possible to pretend a few lines of *`PJL`* (different technology) to the PDF in order to select trays. How complicated are your requirements? Do you need to switch trays in the middle of a job? Multiple times? -- What is your OS platform from which you send of the print job? Why can't you use CUPS and a PostScript-PPD? Then you can specify trays and other features from the command line even...

Comment: @ribald: If it is a Digimaster which supports PDF, you can also control various aspects of the print job simply by inserting *`%%KDK`*-comment lines into the DSC header of the PostScript job.

Comment: Thanks Kurt for the prompt message. I'm sorry I didn't expand any further, but I found some documentation on the printer. It supports KDK commands in postscript. 

I am currently exploring taking the PDF to Postscript. Then inserting KDK commands that specify what pages use what paper type. This is working, but large PS files seem to be having issues (very slow/error prone).

We're using Windows 7. I'm also unfamilar with CUPS but I have read a about it a bit.

Comment: @ribald: Feel free to ask a new `[postscript]`-tagged question should you have problems with the *`%%KDK`* stuff...

Comment: Thanks Kurt, I think I'll make a new post regarding my current issues. So far it works with small files, but having issues with larger ones :(

Comment: @ribald: For Windows there used to be the so-called 'Kodak Print File Downloader' (not a printer driver!). Not sure if it is still available. You could open its GUI, then load a PS, PDF, PCL or TIFF file into its to-be-printed-list of jobs, select a few job options (like trays, stapling, sorting etc.) and send it off to the Digimaster...

Comment: @ribald: You problem may originate from your way/utility how you convert PDF->PostScript. *How* exactly are you doing that?

Comment: Hello, I asked a better question I think that tells more of what I'm doing. Thanks for all your help. For you and anyone else that have any interest in this issue, I'm moving the discussion over to more detailed question of where I'm at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131441/pdf-to-postscript-using-ghostscript-large-files-having-issues-printing