# PDF to PostScript Using Ghostscript: large files having issues printing

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript, postscript

I'm currently using Ghostscript to convert 500 page PDF files into PostScript.

I'm using Windows 7, Ghostscript x64 v 9.16, and a Kodak Digimaster Commercial Printer.

I use the following arguments for GhostScript to convert a PDF into PS:

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.16\bin\gswin64c.exe" 
-dCompressFonts=true 
-dSubsetFonts=true 
-dEmbedAllFonts=true 
-sFONTPATH=C:\Windows\Fonts\ 
-dNOPAUSE 
-dBATCH 
-sDEVICE=ps2write 
-sOutputFile="PostScript.ps" 
"MyPdf.pdf"
```

I then add `%KDK` (proprietary) commands to dictate which pages need to print on which paper by using the `%KDKSlip` command based on the Printer documentation.

The example below would print all pages on Letter duplex except for pages 1/2 and 5/6. Pages 1/2 would print on a paper defined under the name of "YellowPerf", while 5/6 would print on "TriPerf":

```
 %!PS-Adobe-3.0
 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 612 792
 %%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 612.00 792.00
 %%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 916 (ps2write)
 %%LanguageLevel: 2
 %%CreationDate: D:20150506143059-05'00'
 %%Pages: 8
 %%DocumentMedia: Letter 612 792 0 white ()
 %%+ YellowPerf 612 792 0 yellow ()
 %%+ TriPerf 612 792 0 white ()
 %KDKRequirements: duplex
 %KDKSlip: YellowPerf duplex 1
 %%+ TriPerf duplex 5
 %%EndComments
 %%BeginProlog
```

This is then sent to a Kodak Digimaster printer using a Windows command:

```
> COPY PostScript.ps PrinterName
```

This has worked fine with smaller documents, but I'm having issues with larger page sets.

When I attempted to print to the Digimaster using a 500 page PDF to Postscript file, it had errors occur: "Busy, do not reset the RIP".

File size of those that didn't work:

PostScript File Size: 52 MB
PDF File Size: 41 MB

File sizes of those that did work:

PostScript File Size 1MB
PDF File Size: .8 MB

Why does this work fine with smaller files but get hosed on larger files?

Would anyone have any advice?

Comment: Take the PostScript and run it back through Ghostscript and see what happens. If t works the PostScript is almost certainly valid. However we've seen lots of PostScript printers that don't like the output from ps2write (faults in these implementations in every case). You can try creating subsets of the pages using -dFirstPage and -dLastPage and see whether its particular pages or simply sheer quantity that's a problem. If its particular pages we might be able to do something about it. Eg there's a NoT3CCITT switch to fix a specific printer bug.

Comment: Hey Ken, I validated that I could send the file back to PDF. I've reviewed it and it seems identical to the original. The pages are all very similar so I would be shocked if the printer is having issues with a certain page as I'm basically only changing a few fields in each PDF. Do you have any opinion on using the COPY command to send a Postscript to the printer? I am suspecting the FTP command maybe an issue when sending such a large Postscript file to the printer.

Comment: copy should work fine, you should use the /b switch to copy in binary though. Sine the PostScript is valid its probably caused by simply running out of resources, the ps2write output might define a lot of fonts (it depends on the input) which could exhaust VM on a printer. You could try setting -dSubsetFonts=false. You could also ask Kodak of course :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessarily the *filesize* of the PostScript that causes your problem:

- It could be the PostScript itself, or
- it could be that you made a mistake with your editing of the PS files when you inserted the (proprietary) `%KDK`-comments.

Are you sure your text editor doesn't silently change your linefeed characters?! This could also change the binary parts of the PostScript!

Also, I'm not sure if the `copy` command does handle print jobs like it should. I would prefer the `lpr` command (ah... is that even still available on your version of Windows?!)

To debug this and to explore a few different roads to successful printing, I would try a few different steps:

### To debug

- Send the original PostScript, without the added `%%KDK` DSC header comments, to the printer.

  That printer model has a nice feature you can utilize: you can check if its RIP processes the input file completely and successfully without needing to output your 500 pages on (wrong) paper and waste it therefore (you'd also need to discard it afterwards -- too much work too). Just click the red "Stop" button on its user interface monitor.

  Does that one complete the RIP process successfully?

  Yes? Now you can now even print it. Before you do so you can even modify the job settings to select a particular paper tray, by clicking on some button on the interface (can't recall the exact button label though). Then "release" the job and it will print.

  If it worked, you can again turn your attention to get your `%%KDK` lines right.

  If it didn't you have to try another route.

### Check if a different PDF-to-PS converter is working

- Create a PostScript file with the help of `pdftops` (see **here** for the `pdftops.exe` version -- read the README to see which options are available).

  Proceed analog to above: first see if it completes the RIP process. Then continue with your `%KDK` manipulations....

### Check if the direct PDF printing is working

- The Digimaster model can consume PDF directly. (Well, internally it uses its own PDF-to-PS converter, but that isn't visible to the outside -- so it doesn't *really* count as a PDF RIP...)
- If that works, you can even prepend your appropriate `%KDK` comments to the PDF file, similar to the lines below (don't rely on me getting the details right, it's from the top of my head, and memory is decades old!):

  ```
  %!PS-Adobe-3.0
  %%.........................
  %%DocumentMedia: ..........
  %KDKRequirements: .........
  %KDKInserts: ..............
  %KDKSlip: .................
  %KDKBody: .................
  %KDKCovers: ...............
  %KDKPDFPrintAnnotations: on 
  %KDKPDFFitToPage: on
  %KDKBinaryOK: on 
  <esc>%-12345X
  %%Emulation: pdf
  %PDF-1.5
  %...here follow the lines of the original PDF file...
  ...
  ```

### Send jobs via *"Kodak Printfile Downloader"* (KPD)

- For Windows there used to be the so-called 'Kodak Print File Downloader' (KPD). The KPD is an application, not a printer driver. Not sure if it is still available.
- You could open its GUI, then load a PS, PDF, PCL or TIFF file into its to-be-printed-list of jobs. Then select a few job options (like trays, stapling, sorting etc.). Lastly, send the job off to the Digimaster...
- The KPD essentially does the same thing, as you want to achieve:  insert `%KDK` commands into the file header. But you want to do it with a script or an editor (and possibly automatically via a batch process, once it works).
- The KPD requires interactive user activity and cannot be scripted.
- But you can (ab-)use it to intercept the files it creates from the Windows spooling system, study them and then adapt your scripted efforts so that they also work....

---

#### Update

<sup>(I had wanted to add this already in my initial answer. But time ran out, so I skipped it for the time being..)</sup>

### Observe the RIP processing directly at the printer UI

- Digimaster printers have their own built-in touchscreen or flatscreen or tube monitor (depending on the age of the model). They also typically have a full-time operator who knows the machine and its tweaks and peculiarities quite will. The machine may be quite a distance from the user sending a job.
- So the following should be done when debugging a print problem:

  - Ask the operator to set the printer to "stop printing", but still "receiving new jobs".
  - Submit any job(s) you want.
  - Walk up to the printer and its operator.
  - Release the job for RIP-ping and observe what happens:

    - You may see everything going alright and completing until the last page (you know how many pages you submitted, right?)
    - Or you may see the job aborting at a certain page number.
    - Or you may see the printer RIP chewing extremely long on a certain page (or several pages), but finally completing the job.
    - Or you may see the printer RIP hanging with a certain page forever.
    - Or...

  In any case, the details which are observable here may give important clues about where to look next...

Comment: Thanks Kurt! I'll give you an update whenever I have another crack at the printer. I have suspicions that COPY works for smaller PostScript files but has issues with bigger ones when it comes to printing. Using COPY is intended for FTP not Printing. I will try the lpr next. I will also try a PostScript printing utility to see if that makes a difference as well as I work down your list. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Kurt, quick update. I validated the Postscript is correct by sending it back to PDF. I'm in the process of getting a time scheduled with the printer to try lpr command. I spoke to the operator and he said using the COPY command worked, but it was taking 30+ minutes to RIP it. He cancelled the job because it wasn't going to be done for hours.

Comment: We used LPR and a PrintFile Utility (not KPD). Both took 10 minutes before printing anything. They both printed 10 pages then paused to RIP the next...

Comment: @ribald: KPD is gratis for Digimaster customers. The advantage is that you can use it to create *job settings* with it even for PDF spool jobs! If you manage to intercept the KPD-submitted job with the prepended `%KDK` job settings, it is easy to reverse-engineer what your script ought to do... (Maybe that "Print File Utility" is a new name for the former KPD?)

Comment: On all of the postscript files we have tried (whether printing a .ps file using either COPY or LPR commands, or a .PDF printing with PS driver, or using the PrintFile utility) on all of these print methods I ultimately see a strange “green screen” type of screen displayed that have not seen before:  it is labeled “PS_or_PDF Status Monitor”.  This “monitor” screen is displayed from 5-10 minutes prior to going away.

Comment: Once that “status monitor” screen does go away, the page count SLOWLY goes up on the regular printer display.  It may take several minutes, but will finally get to around page 10 and will print those few pages.  Then it pauses for minutes and finally prints about another 10 pages.  This is the same pattern that is repeated over and over again.

Comment: @ribald: ...and this was with the 500pages, 41MByte PDF file and the PS converted from it? How fast is the RIP processing when you send the job as PDF directly (dont care for now about the `%KDK` headers)?

Comment: I'd say in under 10 seconds it would rip the 500 pager to the monitor. I do have good news though! I did your suggestion of adding the %KDK comments to a PDF, and it seems to be working. I just send a large 500 pager with %KDK to test. I'll update you if it works. I'm suspecting the Postscript may not have been optimized?

Comment: you were right about on your bullet point 'Check if the direct PDF printing is working'. It is working and it is printing all 500 pages. I tested with only declaring a few items to print from different paper sources. Tomorrow I do a bigger test, but I'm feeling pretty confident that you gave me the answer. Thanks! I'll update you when I'm 100% its done, and mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: To be specific, I added the %KDK commands to the PDF, and I instructed the operator to do a COPY command to the printer. I assume the Postscript I built wasn't as efficient as the Postscript built by the printer?

Comment: Adding the %KDK commands to the PDF and sending it to the printer did the trick. Thanks!